# Scrollbar disappears / refresh not working in wx.python

Tags: python, wxpython, scrollbar

In the following example the scrollbar disappears after using the calculating button, although the layout function was called. If you manually resize the frame it reappears. This behavior occurs only under windows, in linux the scrollbar functions as it should.

To fix it I tried the functions refresh() and update()  (in layout funtion of class GUI_Diagrams_GHL) - but it didn't help.

I tried to reduce my application to this minmal working example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    '''Frame that contains pretty much everything'''
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        '''Constructor'''
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        notebook = Notebook(self.panel)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook,1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,4)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.panel.Layout()

class Notebook(wx.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Notebook.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, style = wx.BK_DEFAULT)
        tabTwo = GUI_Input_GHL(self) 
        self.AddPage(tabTwo, 'Input')
        tabThree = GUI_Diagrams_GHL(self)  
        self.AddPage(tabThree, 'Diagrams')

class GUI_Input_GHL(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    """This panel contains the input fields for basic data."""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)
        self.label_1 = wx.StaticText(self,-1,label=u'Label 1')
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self,-1,label=u'Start')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.StartCalc, self.button2)
        self.layout()       

    def layout(self):    
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        sizer.Add(self.button2, (8,0),(2,3), flag =wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.label_1, (0,0),flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.SetupScrolling()
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

    def StartCalc(self,event):
        pub.sendMessage('GUI_Diagrams_Listener', message = 'test')

class GUI_Diagrams_GHL(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    """This panel contains diagrams"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)
        self.parent = parent
        self.fig1 = Figure()
        self.fig6 = Figure()
        self.canvas1 = FigCanvas(self,-1,self.fig1)
        self.axes1 = self.fig1.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas6 = FigCanvas(self,-1,self.fig6)
        self.axes6 = self.fig6.add_subplot(111)
        self.dia_R_hat_SetValues('test')
        self.dia_theta_SetValues('test')
        self.layout()
        pub.subscribe(self.diagrams_SetValues, "GUI_Diagrams_Listener")


    def layout(self):
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        sizer.Add(self.canvas1,   (1,0), (12,12), wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.canvas6,  (53,0), (12,12), wx.EXPAND)

        ## I guess here is the problem somewhere:
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.SetupScrolling()
        #self.Fit()
        #self.Layout()
        #self.FitInside()
        #self.AlwaysShowScrollbars(True,True)
        #self.Refresh()
        #self.Update()
        #self.parent.SetSize(self.parent.GetSize())

    def diagrams_SetValues(self, message):
        self.Output = message
        self.dia_R_hat_SetValues(message)
        self.dia_theta_SetValues(message)
        self.layout()

    def dia_R_hat_SetValues(self, Output):
        self.axes1.clear()
        self.axes1.plot(range(15),range(15), 'r-', linewidth = 2)
        self.canvas1.draw()

    def dia_theta_SetValues(self, Output):
        self.axes6.clear()
        self.axes6.plot(range(5),'k')
        self.axes6.set_title(r"Absolute Temperature")
        self.canvas6.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainWindow(None, -1, 'MyApp')
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 4):

I've figured it out myself :)

If you call the layout function of the main panel ('MainWindow.panel.Layout()') after updating the diagrams/in the layout of the diagram class, the whole panel refreshes and
the Scrollbars reappear. So a 'parent.parent.Layout()' worked for me in this case.

Any other suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Zoipi's solution works great for me!    
Thank you.

I'm using a wx.ScrolledPanel with a wx.GridSizer.

First I had a problem of the panel size not updating when adding extra widgets.
I could fix this with the ScrolledPanel's self.FitInside().

Then I had the problem of the scrollbar not appearing until I manually resized the window.

Both problems where fixed by only calling ***self.parent.Layout()*** of the ScrolledPanel.
The self.FitInside() could be removed when calling the parent's Layout().